# How to set the same color value in a cell as the color in a different cell?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

basically the same as the title, for instance How can I conditionally set A2's color to depend on B2's color so that when I change B2's color, A2 also changes to the new color? Even so, is it possible?

I've tried all conditional formatting options and can't seem to find the right one to use

Answer (score 1):

From your question of `for instance How can I conditionally set A2's color to depend on B2's color so that when I change B2's color, A2 also changes to the new color? Even so, is it possible?`, I believe your goal is as follows.

- When the background color of cells of column "B" is changed, you want to change the background color of column "A" to the same color.

In this case, how about using the installable OnChange trigger? When this is used, the sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Spreadsheet, and please set your sheet name. And, [please install OnChange trigger to the function `installedOnChange`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_manually).

```js
function installedOnChange(e) {
  const sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set your sheet name.

  const { source } = e;
  const sheet = source.getActiveSheet();
  if (e.changeType != "FORMAT" || sheet.getSheetName() != sheetName) return;
  const range = sheet.getActiveRange();
  if (range.getColumn() != 2) return;
  const color = range.getBackground();
  range.offset(0, -1).setBackground(color);
}
```

- When you test this script, please set the background color of a cell of column "B". By this, this script is automatically run by the installable OnChange trigger and changes the background color of column "A" to the same color.

#### Testing:

When this script is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

#### Note:

- When you directly run this script with the script editor, an error like `TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'source' of 'e' as it is undefined.` occurs because of no event object. Please be careful about this.

#### Reference:

- [Installable Triggers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable)